# How to install rapidjson c++ library on MacOS?

Tags: c++, cmake

How to install rapidjson c++ library on MacOS Ventura13.4 with help of CMake?

I am following official tutorial: https://github.com/JyoCoin/rapidjson

```
git clone https://github.com/Tencent/rapidjson.git
git submodule update --init
cd rapidjson
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

Error:

```
 15%] Building CXX object example/CMakeFiles/jsonx.dir/jsonx/jsonx.cpp.o
/src/rapidjson/example/jsonx/jsonx.cpp:37:43: error: 'sprintf' is deprecated: This function is provided for compatibility reasons only.  Due to security concerns inherent in the design of sprintf(3), it is highly recommended that you use snprintf(3) instead. [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        return WriteNumberElement(buffer, sprintf(buffer, "%d", i));
```

**UPDATE:**
I can install the library with help of brew

```
brew install rapidjson
brew install pkg-config 
pkg-config --cflags --libs rapidjson

clang++ main.cpp -o res.bin
```

But how can I install with help of CMake?

Comment: `brew install pkg-config` then `pkg-config --cflags --libs rapidjson`. Usually you should use the flags like `-I/opt/homebrew/include -L/opt/homebrew/lib -lrapidjson` for any homebrew installed library.

Comment: It seems that rapidjson examples have not been not adapted for a new version of the compiler. You may edit those examples: e.g. the pointed error could be easily fixed: https://github.com/Tencent/rapidjson/blob/master/example/jsonx/jsonx.cpp#L37. Alternatively, you may disable building the examples by passing additional argument `-DRAPIDJSON_BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF` to `cmake`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ExternalProject to add rapidjson to your project. It will download from git and make it available in your source tree. I was going to write the full answer here but I found a better explanation from a blog page:

https://www.jibbow.com/posts/rapidjson-cmake/